# Asp hidden field not updating value on the server side using jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a hidden field:

```
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenId" runat="server"/>
</ContentTemplate>
```

And the jQuery:

```
var emptyVal = "123";

$("[id*=gridview] td").bind("click", function () {
var row = $(this).parent();
$("[id*=gridview] tr").each(function () {
if ($(this)[0] != row[0]) {
    $("td", this).removeClass("");
}
});
if (!$(this).hasClass("")) {
    $(this).addClass("");
}
else 
{
    $(this).removeClass("");
    $('#<%= hiddenId.ClientID %>').val(emptyVal);
    alert($('#<%= hiddenId.ClientID %>').val());
}
```

The code behind:

```
var value = hiddenId.Value;
```

I added an `onclick` event on the rows of the gridview on the `rowdatabound`:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick","javascript: getElementById('" + hiddenId.ClientID + "').value='" + e.Row.RowIndex + "';");
```

So on every click of the row, the row index is being stored on the hidden field.

My problem here is I can't get the new value on the server side. I used the `alert` on the jquery to test if the value is being updated. It is being updated but when it hit the breakpoint on the server side, I still get the old value.

I even tried using this but still no luck:

```
var hiddenValue = Request.Form[hiddenId.UniqueID];
```

What can I do so I can get the new value from the hidden field? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The purpose of the `jQuery` is to highlight the row of the selected gridview. Upon clicking again the same row, it will remove the highlight of the row. And at the same time, it should remove the value from the hidden field.

*Sample scenario:*

1) User will click a row
2) The hidden field will be populated by `int` 0 for example.
3) When the user click the same row again, it will remove the value of the hidden field.

Comment: can you show actual jquery code?

Comment: `$(this).addClass("");` :) what's that for exactly?

Comment: Please see updates on my question @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: Change your hiddenfield to a textbox to make sure the value is there.

Comment: What do you mean? I can get the value on the server side, but not the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the code below:

```
var hiddenValue = Request.Form[hiddenId.Value];
```

Comment: for your previous question bind your ddl after inserting value

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery selectors look strange but I may not be understanding all you are doing.  Could you not use:

```
$('#hiddenId').val(emptyVal);
```

Also, it looks like your Jquery selector is using one value:

```
$('#<%= hiddenId.ClientID %>')
```

But your Request.Form references something different:

```
hiddenId.UniqueID
```

Comment: could you add what the rendered html (of the hidden field) looks like to your question?

Comment: I added a sample scenario

Comment: You've got an onclick event bound to your row in your code behind and a click event bound on your column in your Jquery...could it be the jquery bind is being overridden by the onclick you've set in your code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the standard html input tag like this (no runat=server):

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenId" name="hiddenId" value="" />
```

Then in your code behind reference it like this:

```
var value = Request.Form["hiddenId"];
```

Of course you will need to modify your jQuery and other code behind code to use the correct id.

Comment: It did not worked. Still giving me the old value but on the `alert`, the new value is shown..

Comment: When are you posting back to the server?  On a button click?  Also, what is happening in your Page_Load?

Comment: I just call a method on the `onclick` event of the button. Do I need an asynchronous postback to reflect the new value?

Comment: I am going to need to see more code in order to help you any further. The relevant aspx and code behind code would be helpful.