# Accessing client side array on server side ASP.net - not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, server, esri

I am using `esri` javascript API's in my case. When the user draws a polygon on a map, all the selected features are assigned to an array on client side. I want to access that array on server side.  I developed the code, but I am unable to access the array on server side. The array on server side is null.

```
function Wells(event) {
    var results = new Array();
    arrayUtil.forEach(event.features, function (feature) {
        results.push(feature.attributes.UWI)
        dom.byId('messages').innerHTML = "<b>Selected Wells: " + results;
    });
    var hid = document.getElementById("myHiddenId");
    hid.value = results.join(',');
} // client side code
<body>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="myHiddenId" runat="server">
   </asp:HiddenField>
</body>
// server side
string[] storesarray = myHiddenId.Value.Split(',');
```

Comment: Just a possibility if you're doing WebForms... Is `myHiddenId` the id of the tag when it makes it to the browser? I'd check that in your developer tools in the browser. If you're in a Content Template of any sort, WebForms may be adding a prefix on the id attribute. Otherwise, I'd put a breakpoint at `hid.value = results.join(',');` and see if this is getting set before it hits the server

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978130/asp-hidden-field-not-updating-value-on-the-server-side-using-jquery

Comment: Apart from using `ClientID` to get the actual id of the hidden field (or another way to access the field), there are some more things that needs to be in place for it to work. The field has to be in a form, you have to post that form back to the server, and you can only access the data after the postback, not in the initial request for the page.

Comment: I got the issue solved. Since I was using Master Page, Adding this statement solved the issue. Thank you everyone for their suggestions.                                                                   var hid = document.getElementById('<%=Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder2").FindControl("myHiddenId").ClientID %>');